# Do airways with multiple numbers (e.g., J89-101) imply combined segments?

Tags: airways

On SkyVector, I see many airways with 'multiple' names such as J16-36 or even J89-94-100-128. I can't find any information on how to interpret these names.

I'm guessing it's a convention to say that for some portion of the airways, J89 and J94 overlap - but presumably it's still valid to simply route along J94 including those shared segments?

[image]
[Example near KORD](https://skyvector.com/?ll=43.31318813791902,-88.94348144413001&chart=304&zoom=3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, from your example J34-68-538 are jet routes that share a segment and aircraft on different routes may travel the same segments between waypoints. A complete explanation is in the FAA's [Aeronautical Chart User Guide.](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/)

[image]

Comment: In which section of the aero guide is the explanation please? I couldn't find it.